# Can't troubleshoot undefined method "klass" for nil:NilClass; checked all my associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My models look like this:

```
class ContractShipment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shipment_lots, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
  has_many :liquor_lots, through: :shipment_lots
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipment_lots
end

class ShipmentLot < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contract_shipment, optional: true
  has_many :liquor_lots
end

class LiquorLot < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shipment_lot, optional: true
end
```

When I try to get run the following query, I get the "no method 'klass' for nil:NilClass" error.

```
LiquorLot.joins(shipment_lot: :contract_shipment)
         .where(tank_batch_id: 1, contract_shipments: {id: 1})
         .sum("liquor_lots.package_weight_kg * liquor_lots.package_count")
```

I've looked, and re-looked at my associations and I can't seem to understand what I'm missing.  I've also tried making both of my joins plural (`shipment_lot(s): contract_shipment(s)`) and neither of these options work.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Edit:  the SQL query I'm trying to generate is:

```
SELECT SUM(liquor_lots.package_weight_kg * liquor_lots.package_count) 
FROM "liquor_lots" 
INNER JOIN "shipment_lots" ON "shipment_lots"."id" = "liquor_lots"."shipment_lot_id" 
INNER JOIN "contract_shipments" ON "contract_shipments"."id" = "shipment_lots"."contract_shipment_id" 
WHERE "liquor_lots"."tank_batch_id" = 1 AND "contract_shipments"."id" = 1
```

And this returns the value I'm expecting.  Just want to avoid writing explicit SQL.

Comment: Not sure where your error is coming from but you could change the join to `joins(:shipment_lot)` and the where to `where(tank_batch_id: 1, shipment_lots: {contract_shipment_id: 1})` or you need to add `belongs_to :contract_shipment` to `ShipmentLot` for that query to have a chance. Also to my knowledge you cannot pass that string to `sum` you can "sum" a column by name or use a block to leverage `Enumerable#sum`

Comment: There were other associations that I excluded for brevity when I copied and pasted.  It was always there, but I've edited to include it. 

Regarding the sum, the entire statement works as written if I remove the `where(contract_shipments: {id: 1}` condition.

Comment: I see you edited the first part, and that works, thank you!  Not sure why I was trying to join an additional table when I already had the necessary data.

Though..I still am curious why it's happening.